# Setting up file permissions for a Group

Tags: linux, permissions, users

I am setting up a system wherein I (operating via the sudo prefix) want any added users in my system to be part of a group which has access to a single directory. Access can be defined as pulling documents out-of, placing documents into and reading/editing documents in this directory.

I would want most other directories to be either invisible or out-of-reach for the users of this group.

I assume that it would be best to setup permission for the group such that any user in that group has this sort of access to only that folder and add new users to that group whenever they are created.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Sorry for short comment, I am on phone. But basically you need to create a directory owned by your group. You then need to use `chmod g+s directory` to set the setgid bit on the directory. See the link for an intro https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-4883/secfile-69/index.html